# How do i add a class in datatable column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

How do i add a class in datatable column???

Here is the code in columnDefs:

```
{
                 targets: 6,
                 render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                     if ('1' === '1') {
                         //data = '<a  onclick="TicketDetails(' + (row.Id) + ') " >' + data + '</a>';
                         data = '<span class="label label-sm label-warning"> ' + data + ' </span>';
                         { className: 'label label-sm label-warning' }
                     }

                     return data;
                 }
             }
```

this is a status column in datatable.
if the status value will be 1 then the result output be.

```
<span class="label label-sm label-warning"> New </span>
```

if the status(i.e.the output data) is 2.then.result will be:

```
<span class="label label-sm label-default"> Pending </span>
```

id status data is 3.

then.

```
<span class="label label-sm label-success"> Completed </span>
```

how do i check and create this on datatable column of server side datatable???

here is the columns:

```
 "columns": [
                     //{ "data": '' },
                      { "data": "CreatedDate" },
                      { "data": "Title" },


                      { "data": "Name" },
                      { "data": "Email" },
                      { "data": "AssignTo" },
                      { "data": "Status" }
          ]
```

any one suggest me ???

Comment: Then use the suggested switch in your `render` method ...If `switch (data) { case '1'` and so on.

Comment: just put in a answer

Comment: how do i assign this class..

Comment: return different strings with different classes.  `case 1: return                          data = '<span class="label label-sm label-warning"> ' + data + ' </span>'; break;` case 2 :  label-default instead of label-warning etc.

Comment: the case not working

Comment: you put in a ans

Comment: the case statement in columnDefs not working

Comment: just put a particular answer

Comment: case conditions not working.

Comment: is there any other way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 6 columns in your `columns` array but you're using `targets: 6` which refers to seventh column.

Use the code below:

```js
columnDefs: [
   {
      {
          targets: 5,
          render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
             if(type === 'display'){
                if(data == 1){
                   data = '<span class="label label-sm label-warning"> New </span>';
                } else if(data == 2){
                   data = '<span class="label label-sm label-default"> Pending </span>';
                } else if(data == 3){
                   data = '<span class="label label-sm label-success"> Completed </span>';
                }
             }

             return data;
          }
      }
   }
]
```